# got error while trying to use @FindBy annotation in selenium

Tags: selenium

I tried to use @FindBy annotation as part of object repository in selenium-POM approach in eclipse

when I included the @FindBy annotation, the eclipse IDE is giving following error:

"the annotation @FindBy is disallowed in this location"

I browsed google to find if any posted such a problem scenario, but failed to find any.

could anyone help me understand the scenario?

Thank you for contributing your valuable time and efforts!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qlA9.jpg)

Comment: show us your code snippet where you are using @FindBy. Also take a look at your imports

Comment: hello Champ, thank you for responding... It error was gone, and I don't know how it was fixed... however, here is the code I tried: