# Getting an error while trying to use @FindBy annotation in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, testng-eclipse, findby

I did come across this issue here but according to the thread the "error was gone, and I don't know how it was fixed"...
[got error while trying to use @FindBy annotation in selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51774993/got-error-while-trying-to-use-findby-annotation-in-selenium)

Here is the code I have written. The strange thing is I already have another web element defined on the page object class and it works fine. I just can't seem to understand what the problem is. I am just learning selenium and have never encountered this issue before. I have tried searching the web for answers but cannot seem to find an answer for this particular issue.

This is the first web element on the page object class and it works fine.

```
// Profile button element
@FindBy(xpath="//div[@class='container']//nav//li[2]//a[1]")
@CacheLookup // is used to improve the performance 
static WebElement profileBtn;
```

With this element (on same page object class) I get "The annotation @FindBy is disallowed for this location". I have tried restarting eclipse and cleaning the project but it will not allow this second element.

```
@FindBy(xpath="//div[@id='stateDropdown-styler']//div[@class='jq-selectbox__trigger']")
@CacheLookup // is used to improve the performance
WebElement clickProvinceDropDownArrow()
```

Comment: Just remove `()` from `WebElement clickProvinceDropDownArrow()`. @mentallurg provided more robust answer

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I figured out about two hours later what I had done wrong. Much appreciated though!

Answer (score 3):

See the [definition of @FindBy annotation](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/FindBy.java). It is applicable to fields and classes only, not to methods. It reduces the amount of code that you would otherwise need to write to locate an element and to store it into a member variable.

If you are using page object pattern, then define a member variable with this annotation. If you want to make this element available outside of your page object, implement a getter method that returns this member variable.

```
@FindBy(xpath="//div[@id='stateDropdown-styler']//div[@class='jq-selectbox__trigger']")
private WebElement clickProvinceDropDownArrow;

public WebElement getClickProvinceDropDownArrow() {
    return clickProvinceDropDownArrow;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am still new to automation testing (in coop)  and I mistakenly put the () in when it should have been ; I will inquire with my coop lead about the use of the getter method you suggest. This was not suggested in any of my classes. I assume that this is considered a best practice though.